# knitr sometimes wraps the code in chunks inappropriately

Tags: r, latex, knitr, beamer

In `.Rnw` files producing a LaTeX beamer presentation, I find that occasionally `knitr` causes the code in a chunk to wrap, as if it is continuous text, even though the chunk option `tidy=FALSE` is in effect (I've set this as default).

Most code chunks are formatted correctly.  Here are a couple of examples of chunks that get wrapped.

```
  It is often useful to plot the data for the binary distinction between $y_i = 0$
  vs. $y_i > 0 $ as in logistic regression models.

<<phd-zero, h=5, w=5, out.width='0.5\\textwidth', size='footnotesize' >>=
plot(factor(articles==0) ~ mentor, data=PhdPubs,
    ylevels=2:1, ylab="Zero articles",
    breaks=quantile(mentor, probs=seq(0,1,.2)), cex.lab=1.25)
@
```

Which prints like this:

[image]

Here is another example:

```
    For simplicity, we use all predictors for both the zero model
    and the non-zero model.

<<size='footnotesize', tidy=FALSE>>=
library(countreg)
phd.zip <- zeroinfl(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="poisson")
phd.znb <- zeroinfl(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="negbin")

phd.hp  <- hurdle(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="poisson")
phd.hnb <- hurdle(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="negbin")
@
```

This one appears like this:

[image]

(Note that both of these examples use model formulas, and in both outputs, the
`~` character does not appear in the output.  However, other cases
using model formulas work as expected.)

As I mentioned, almost **all other code chunks print normally**, respecting the spacing in the source for the chunks.  What could be causing this problem?

I have also checked whether there are extra spaces at the end of lines in the offending chunks, but there are not.

If it makes any difference, I compile the presentation using `knitr::knit2pdf()`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior arises when you forget to use the `[fragile]` option for the frame.  Often this causes an error, but in this case it mysteriously causes the bad formatting observed.

This works:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Example: Phd Publications}
    For simplicity, we use all predictors for both the zero model
    and the non-zero model.

<<fit-models, size='footnotesize', tidy=FALSE>>=
library(countreg)
phd.zip <- zeroinfl(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="poisson")
phd.znb <- zeroinfl(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="negbin")

phd.hp  <- hurdle(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="poisson")
phd.hnb <- hurdle(articles ~ ., data=PhdPubs, dist="negbin")
@
\end{frame}
```